# Ember dependency injection not working with router in Ember 1.11

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember component where I need both the store and the router. I'm trying to inject them using `Ember.inject.service`. It works when I inject the store, but not the router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
  routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  classNames: ['my-component'],
  schema: Ember.computed('store', 'routing', function schema() {

    // This works. Shows up when I log it.
    const store = this.get('store');

    // This doesn't
    const routing = this.get('routing');

    // return schema from store. This works.
  }),
});

export default MyComponent
```

I'm on Ember version 1.11.3. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check if you have this in your packages? `ember-routing/lib/services/routing.js` Maybe you just miss the file. Also, do you have any errors? And did you try injecting from initializer for example?

Comment: @reillyethan: what packages? In the ember build itself? No errors. I am injecting on component initialization currently.

Comment: I thought maybe routing service wasn't installed correctly or smth but that doesn't make sense. Well, I don't know why it doesn't work. Docs says this service is private but can be opened. I don't know what they mean by this, you could see the comment [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.7.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/services/routing.js#L13) maybe it's not as opened as store or smth

Comment: Why do you need routing service for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Ember 1.13, but in my Ember 2.x app, I inject the router as you described above and can then transition as follows:

```
    this.get('routing.router').transitionTo('routeName', model, {
      queryParams: {
        queryName: queryValue
      }
    });
```

ps: It is generally considered best practice to pass an action closure into a component which would take care of the route transition, rather than making the component responsible for handling the transition.